# How to resize a ZFS partition in Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, gparted, zfs

How do I resize/shrink a ZFS partition in Ubuntu using gparted?
As gparted doesn't support ZFS file system to shrink, so how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

The ZFS filesystem does not currently allow for pools or devices to be resized (since ZFS is much more than a filesystem - and ZFS doesn't really use "partitions" in the same sense as other filesystems).

The only possible way to resize a ZFS volume is to:

1. Back up the volume data somewhere
2. Remove the old volume (Zpool)
3. Create a new volume (Zpool)
4. Restore your volume data

At some point in the future, this functionality might be added to ZFS, but I wouldn't count on it happening anytime soon.

See [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/238208/which-version-of-zfs-allows-shrinking-of-a-pool) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/zfs/comments/sx6ohz/reduce_zfs_partition_size/) for reference.